# Can someone optimize the following code snippet for better performance?

Tags: javascript

Can someone optimize the following code snippet for better performance?

```
function whichSideOfTheBoard(name) {
  const light = ['Luke', 'Obi-Wan', 'Front']; 
  const dark = ['Vader', 'Palpatine'];
  
  return light.includes(name) ? 'light' : 
    dark.includes(name) ? 'dark' : 'unknown';
};

whichSideOfTheBoard('Front');
// returns "light"
whichSideOfTheBoard('Back');
// returns "unknown"
```

Comment: What about this code is making it perform poorly?

Comment: Can *you*?  What happens when you try?  How have you measured the difference in your attempts?  Do you even need to optimize this in any meaningful way?  How are you trying to optimize it?  Faster execution time?  Lower memory footprint?  Fewer keystrokes?  Fewer syllables when describing it aloud?  Something else?

Comment: This code does nothing. It has no side effects or observable behavior. You can replace it with an empty script. A good C++ optimizer would simply remove similar C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

Define an object which has the key of 'name' and value of dark/light and simply just return obj[name] || 'unknown'

```
function whichSideOfTheBoard(name) {
  const names = {
    Luke: 'light',
    'Obi-Wan': 'light',
    Front: 'light',
    Vader: 'dark',
    Palpatine: 'dark'
  };
  return names[name] || 'unknown';
};
```